# How to add date in timeline of GANTT in mermaid with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mermaid

We are trying to generate a Gantt Chart in mermaid using [Mermaid Preview Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vstirbu.vscode-mermaid-preview). But when we try to preview we get a preview like this.

[image: Mermaid Preview Gantt chart in VS Code]

But with the same code when we try with mermaids live editor [Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/) we got more clear picture with dates are properly displayed

How can we update Visual Studio code Settings for the date should be corrected and more readable Gantt Chart

[image: s]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your search for this :

```
axisFormat %d/%m
```

Doc : https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gantt

Example :

```
gantt
    title Gantt
    dateFormat  DD-MM-YYYY
    axisFormat %d/%m
    
    section One
    Task One            : 07-05-2019, 7d
    Task Two            : 09-05-2019, 7d
```